# Line integral of two variable by parametrization.

Tags: integration, parametrization, line-integrals

Given $f(x,y) = x^2y$, I am computing line integral of $f$ on the curve $r(t) = (t^3,t^2)$parametrized on the interval $-2<t<2$.

I was thinking mapping $r$ means $x = t^3$ and $y = t^2$ so I directly substituted into $f$ so that

$\int x^2y ds =\int_{-2}^{2} t^6*t^2 \sqrt{(3t^2)^2+(2t)^2} dt$.

the parametrized integral looks not solvable thus I am suspecting I misunderstood the question. Am I on right track or the integral is already wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have $f(x,y)= x^2y$. But you are on the curve $r(t)= (t^3,t^2)$ for $-2 \leq t \leq 2$. But then $x= t^3$ and $y= t^2$ so that on this curve, $f(r(t))= (t^3)^2 t^2= t^6 \cdot t^2= t^8$. Now $ds= \sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}\;dt=\sqrt{(3t^2)^2+(2t)^2}\;dt= \sqrt{9t^4+4t^2}\;dt$. Then you have
$$
\int f \;ds= \int_{-2}^2 t^8\sqrt{9t^4+4t^2}\;dt
$$
So you are exactly correct!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then is there any method to solve this integral? When I put this equation into Wolfram, the answer includes hyper geometric function so it doesn't look right.

Comment: @NMZ I'm not sure what you typed, I get something integrable, but certainly not pretty https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bt%5E8*Sqrt%5B9t%5E4%2B4t%5E2%5D%5D

Comment: A method: factor out a $t^2$ from the root, use $t=2/3\tan a$ and obtain a trigonometric integral. Then turn that integral by substitution into an integral of a large polynomial and then integrate term-by-term.